# Change wallpaper programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

I'm making an app that change the wallpaper programmatically.
That's my code :

```
do{
    let imgurl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: self.app_path+self.wallpaper_folder_name+self.file_name);
    let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared();
    if let screen = NSScreen.main(){
        try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [:]);
        do{
            print("Awesome !");
        }
    }
}catch{
    print(error);
}
```

And it's working (partially).

**The problem is :**

If I look at the desktop and change the wallpaper like this :
[image]
It's working :D

But if I change my wallpaper when I'm in an app **in fullScreen** like this :
[image]
The wallpaper don't change (without error).
So, do you know why ? And how to solve it ?

---

**EDIT**
tryed to use that code

```
let screens = NSScreen.screens()!;
print("SIZE : "+String(screens.count));
for screen in screens{
    print("TRY ...");
    try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [:]);
    do{
        print("DONE");
    }
}
```

But it prints me "SIZE : 1" (when I'm on an app in fullscreen)...
And don't change me my wallpaper :/

Comment: Have you checked the value of `NSScreen.main()` when another app is in fullscreen mode, perhaps this is interfering with it?

Comment: The command "print(screen)" returns me the same thing : <NSScreen: 0x608000062b00> In all cases.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it sets the background of the fullscreen window desktop – when an app goes fullscreen the OS puts it into a new desktop.

Comment: You are right : NSScreen.main() : Returns the screen object containing the window with the keyboard focus (look at the edit)